# $C=\sum_{i=1}^{n} Z(X_{i}-\mu)Z^{T}$ . Find $Z$ if $X$ follows a bivariate normal distribution

Tags: matrices, normal-distribution, self-learning, means

Let $C=VDV^T$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $V^T V=I$. Now I have an expression of the form $$C=\sum_{i=1}^n Z(X_i-\mu)(X_i-\mu)^{T}Z^T$$ Here $C$ is known and $X_i$ are known, moreover $X_i$ follows a standard bivariate gaussian distribution ($X \in \mathcal{N}(0,I_{2\times 2})$). We need to find the value of $Z.$ $C$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix and $Z$ is also a $2 \times 2 $ matrix. How should I proceed? Everything except $Z$ is known or can be calculated. We just want to write $Z$ in terms of all the other variables.

Comment: Is $\mu$ known?

Comment: Yes, the value of $X_{i}$'s and $\mu$ are known. The only unknown is Z

Comment: And by $(X_i-\mu)$ you mean a $2\times2$ diagonal matrix?  So basically you are asking for $Z$ to solve the matrix equation $C=ZMZ^T$ where $C$ and $M$ are given?  For starters, the determinants of $C$ and $M$ had better have the same sign, or there is no $Z$.  Otherwise, don't the SVD decompositions of $M$ and $C$ contain what you want?

Comment: @kimchilover : No. $X_i-\mu$ is not a $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix. It is a $2\times 1$ vector-valued random variable that is distributed as $\mathcal N(0, I_{2\times2}).$ That's one thing about this problem where there is no uncertainty about what is meant.

Comment: Is $C$ supposed to be random or constant? If $C$ is constant, then $Z$ is a random vector, and the problem would be to find its distribution.

Comment: I have edited the question. I forgot to multiply $(X_{i}-\mu)^{T}$ in the middle. I have added this now. Everything expect Z is known. So we just need Z in terms of all the other variables

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\sum_i (X_i-\mu)(X_i-\mu)^T$ have the eigenvector (or spectral) decomposition  $S=Q\Lambda Q^T$, where $QQ^T=I$.  Now you want
$$ 
VDV^T = ZSZ^T = Z Q \Lambda Q^T Z^T.
$$
Then $Z=VD^{1/2}\Lambda^{-1/2}Q^T$ does the trick, where $\Lambda^{-1/2}$ and  $D^{1/2}$ are the obvious diagonal matrices.

Comment: We sample $X_{i}$'s from a bivariate normal distribution and the size of our sample n=100. For a bunch of points how would you calculate the singular value decomposition

Comment: I misstated the need for SVD.  In fact these computations only need you to find eigenvectors and values of $S$, which some subroutine on your computer does for you.  The expression $VD^{1/2}\Lambda{-1/2}Q^T$ in fact *is* the SVD of $S$, but you don't need to compute the SVD to find out $Q$ and $\Lambda$ to get $Z$.  (I worked backwards, and didn't realize at first that an SVD computation is not needed.)